# Error building in Xcode 6.3, 6.4, using Unity 5.0, 5.1 IL2CPP Scripting BK ARM64

Tags: xcode, plugins, unity-game-engine, arm64

I have a problem, trying to upload an **Unity3d** build to test in appstore / Itunes Connect.

I use **neatplug** plugins   (FacebookSNS, AppleIAP).

when i choose IL2CPP scripting backend  to give support to **ARM64** Architecture and try upload for testing.
It doesn't works in **IPAD Air (crash)**. and in Iphone is a bit lacking (slow).

using  Unity 5.1.1p4 and 5.1.1p3  and  5.1.2f1, **NOW I have apple mach-o linker errors** and very much warnings in Xcode 6.3, 6.4

Thanks alot !
any help may be welcome

Answer (score 1):

Do provide the error logs that will help us uinderstnding the exact cause of problem you facing.

**Do make sure you are following these rules:**

By default it will build for Universal architecture (including both ARM64 and ARMv7), if needed you might switch to specific architecture in Player Settings. There is number of things that should be done before your application is up and running in 64 bits:

1. You need 64 bit capable device to test on. These are all iOS devices
   with A7 or later chip (currently these are: iPhone 5S, iPad Air,
   iPad Mini Retina, iPhone 6, iPhone 6 Plus, iPad Mini 3, iPad Air 2).
2. You need all your native plugins to be compiled with 64 bit support
   (or be provided as source code). If you are using 3rd party plugin,
   you should contact your plugin vendor to obtain 64 bit capable and
   IL2CPP compatible version of that plugin.
3. If you are the plugin vendor or just have your own native plugins
   then you need keep couple of things in mind: IL2CPP is not
   API-compatible (which is unexposed) with the Mono Runtime API, which
   means if plugin is using mono_* functions won’t link anymore. The
   best way to resolve this issue is to switch to managed
   delegate/callback approach and pass your managed callbacks to the
   native side of plugin and call them back from there when some native
   data or event arrives.
4. All plugins that come as precompiled static libraries (.a files)
   should now include ARM64 slice. When doing native code/type
   conversion keep in mind that pointers and longs are now 64 bit wide
   and ints are still 32 wide.

As far as my understanid you have pluglin related issue, they need to be compiled with 64 bit support ask your vender regarding same. adn be sure that in xcode all the necessary frameworks have beed added (if need to be added for you mentioned plugins) by you before making build on device.

Comment: thanks Harschell !
exactly,like you say,  the error was caused by plugins, neatplug has not been updated to support the new 64-bit architectures in Xcode 6.3, 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

After realize a test, I checked that the neatplug plugins are the cause of the errors.
are good plugins but without this actualization are unserviceable.

I tried ask this to the vendor,  without no response.

I'm looking for a new supplier. maybe prime 31

thanks alot!

Comment: yeah prime 31 all plungs are compiled with 64 bit .